# ShinyApp accents and special characters problems

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I would like to know how I can solve the problem of accents and special characters, I don't know why special characters (´,ñ, etc) appear wrong, with the code I don't have any problem but when running the shiny app all the labels where this type of characters are appear as an attachment in the image below. I have read about saving with utf-8 encoding but the problem is still not fixed, below I share information about my session.

wrong labels: Número, Gráfico, Comunicación
[image]

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] stringi_1.6.1     plotly_4.10.0     ggplot2_3.3.5    
 [4] dplyr_1.0.7       shinyFiles_0.9.1  visNetwork_2.1.0 
 [7] openxlsx_4.2.4    shinyalert_2.0.0  lubridate_1.7.10 
[10] data.table_1.14.2 DT_0.20           shinyjs_2.0.0    
[13] shiny_1.7.1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6        lattice_0.20-38   tidyr_1.1.4      
 [4] assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.27     utf8_1.2.1       
 [7] mime_0.10         R6_2.5.1          evaluate_0.14    
[10] httr_1.4.2        pillar_1.6.4      rlang_0.4.11     
[13] uuid_0.1-4        lazyeval_0.2.2    fontawesome_0.2.2
[16] rstudioapi_0.13   jquerylib_0.1.4   rmarkdown_2.11   
[19] foreign_0.8-75    htmlwidgets_1.5.4 munsell_0.5.0    
[22] compiler_3.6.3    httpuv_1.6.1      xfun_0.30        
[25] pkgconfig_2.0.3   htmltools_0.5.2   tidyselect_1.1.1 
[28] tibble_3.1.1      fansi_0.4.2       viridisLite_0.4.0
[31] crayon_1.4.2      withr_2.4.2       later_1.2.0      
[34] grid_3.6.3        jsonlite_1.7.2    xtable_1.8-4     
[37] gtable_0.3.0      lifecycle_1.0.1   DBI_1.1.2        
[40] magrittr_2.0.1    scales_1.1.1      zip_2.2.0        
[43] cli_3.1.0         cachem_1.0.4      fs_1.5.0         
[46] promises_1.2.0.1  sp_1.4-6          bslib_0.3.1      
[49] ellipsis_0.3.2    generics_0.1.1    vctrs_0.3.8      
[52] tools_3.6.3       glue_1.4.2        purrr_0.3.4      
[55] crosstalk_1.1.1   rsconnect_0.8.25  fastmap_1.1.0    
[58] yaml_2.2.1        colorspace_2.0-1  maptools_1.1-2   
[61] knitr_1.36        sass_0.4.0
```